# What happens when two companies sponsor the same tag?

Tags: discussion, advertising, sponsored-tags

This is just me wondering, it is not meant to start another discussion on the sponsored tags. But what happens when two companies want to sponsor a tag? For example, I see Silverlight is sponsored by Telerik. What if Infragistics wanted to sponsor this too?

Comment: You could figure this out by going undercover as an interested party.

Comment: Ohhh so those icons on some tags are sponsorship? Like ad revenue? Clever!

Comment: **THUNDERDOME!!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the same thing that happens if two companies want to use the same billboard :)

Advertising is finite. It's nice (for the site) when demand exceeds supply since they can charge more and dictate more agreeable terms.

Comment: Marked as an answer. Indeed, it will probably just be a business decision from the StackOverflow people.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this happens we just pick the first, based on an internal priority.

We do not display more than one sponsor per tag.

Comment: I love Stack Exchange, but you guys simply have too much whitespace going on.  Imagine the profit you could make with a scheme that looked more like, say [this](http://www.dogtipper.com/celebrity-canines-photos/uploaded_images/prnphotos078538-NORTH-SHORE-ANIMAL-790188.jpg).  No more wasted pixels!

Comment: @Popular, awesome plan ! :)